# Intuition behind the visualization of the following inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, graphing-functions

From the solution of the equation:

```
Solve[a Sin[\[Theta]/2]^2 + b Sin[\[Theta]/2] Cos[\[Theta]/2] + c == 0, \[Theta]] // Simplify // PowerExpand
```

Take the inequality:

$\sqrt{b^4-4b^2c(a+c)}>0$

The solution for it is [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%28b%5E4-4*b%5E2*c*%28a%2Bc%29%29%3E0+solve+for+a%2Cb%2Cc%2CReals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usbr7.jpg):

$\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a)<c<\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a)$

$a, b$ and $c$ are defined as follows:

$a=2 \cdot (M \cdot M \cdot x) \cdot y$

$b=2 \cdot(M \cdot x) \cdot y$

$c=x \cdot y$

here $x,y$ are arbitrary unit vectors

$M$ - skew-symmetric matrix

My intuition tells me that one can move from mathematical abstraction to a visual geometric representation of the solution of this inequality. Either some kind of vector diagram is spinning in my head, or something with a parallelepiped or a circle.

**I need a hint:** how can I display the solution of the inequality in this case?

**EDIT:**

I discovered something.If we build two-dimensional graphs (with a fixed $a$), then we can see the following.

```
RegionPlot[{Evaluate@Table[b^4 - 4 b^2 c (a + c) > 0, {a, 1/2, 1, 0.25}]}, {b, -2, 2}, {c, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> Small, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

It can be seen that the region for solving the inequality is an "hourglass" with a certain width of the "neck", which is $=a$. Thus, if the parameter $c$ is within this "hourglass", the inequality is satisfied. It should be noted that the smaller $a$, the smaller the width of the neck and the higher the risk that the inequality may not be feasible, since the risk of $c$ falling out of the hourglass is higher.

Comment: $M$ skew symmetric matrix $n \times n$ with $n=...$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $3 \times 3$

Comment: Why don't you consider $|b|\sqrt{b^2-4c(a+c)}>0$ instead of $\sqrt{b^4-4b^2c(a+c)}>0$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Of course, this inequality can also be used!  Does it somehow change the approach to visualization?

Comment: @JeanMarie see my edit, please

Comment: If your issue, considering expression $|b|\sqrt{b^2-4c(a+c)}>0$, is to have an idea on the values of $(a,b,c)$ such that $b^2-4c(a+c) \ge 0$, this inequation can be transformed into $a \ge \underbrace{\frac{b^2}{4c}-c}_{f_b(c)}$ the RHS giving a family of hyperbolas parametrized by $b$, which should give the same regions as the ones you have obtained in a different way.

Comment: Dealing with the matrix interpretation, I wouldn't be surprized that it has someting to do with "Schur's complements".

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it would be interesting to see that. Well, maybe someone else will post something. Yesterday I tried it myself, but I have not yet received a result in the "field" of matrices and vectors.